# Apache Cordova - Visual Studio 2015 - Unable to build signed apk

Tags: android, visual-studio-2015, apk, apache-cordova

Error       Android packages must be signed when debugging using the Release configuration. To configure Android signing, follow instructions at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=613579  BlankCordovaApp4

```
key.store=E:\key.keystore
key.alias=asdfgh
key.store.password=asdfgh
key.alias.password=asdfgh
```

This are the following values i have given in the ant.properties files.

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore E:\key.keystore -alias asdfgh -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 1000
```

I tried to add another slash for key.store like this

```
key.store=E:\\key.keystore
```

During the build, I got the following information

```
'keystore' and 'alias' need to be specified to generate a signed archive.
```

I entered the details, in the res -> native -> android -> ant.properties
  I tried to install that apk in my mobile and i got error saying "Install failed"

```
Error code -102
```

Answer (score 1):

I need to add those keystore and passwords in **build.json**

Answer (score 0):

first u goto inside bin in java where installed in your system .copy the path 
it may be like this C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin then run command to create key in command prompt.after entering some details u get key. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/phonegap/phonegap_app_contents.htm
then fill the datails entered when creating key in build.json like below.the the problem related to key will be solved

```
"android": {
    "release": {

        "keystore": "my-release-key.keystore",
        "storePassword": "nidhin",
        "alias": "nidhin",
        "password": "nidhin",
        "keystoreType": ""
    }
 }
```